# Trump pardons...Trump?

Tags: united-states, president, executive, pardon

If Gerald Ford was able to preemptively pardon Richard Nixon, what would stop Trump from doing that to himself? Why doesn't every president do that, just in case?

Comment: Most Presidents believe that that would tarnish their legacy. Where there is a pardon, there must be a crime, the public perception would go. And the idea that "most" Presidents do routinely do criminal acts is just plain wrong.

Comment: It's amazing how many people believe The President has committed a crime yet cannot name what that crime was.

Comment: @FrankCedeno I agree. The reason I ask is because there has been a lot of discussion about it.